# How to write "good" user interface texts?

Tags: user-interface

Many applications are let down by the quality of the 'writing' in their user interfaces: typically, poor spelling, grammar, inconsistent tone, and worse yet, "humour" are the usual offenders.

Are there good resources that can help developers to write UI messages that give a professional and positive impression to your customers, even when your code's going to hell in a handcart?

**Thanks, all** — Some great resources here, so I will CW this question. I'm accepting Adam Sill's answer because it's the one that (as a developer of desktop apps) I found most pertinent.

Comment: one of the things I like about open source software is the humor in the UI.  for instance, the sudo command can insult you when you get your password wrong.  And the infamous "printer on fire" error message

Comment: Nothing's funnier than "format c:"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since XP, I've been a fan of the Windows UX Guidelines sections that cover how to properly structure text (how to ask questions, how to make assertions in dialogs, etc).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa974176.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa974175.aspx

Comment: I must admit, Windows Vista labels, messages, prompts, and help text are very friendly and warm to the users. When I saw the links above, I now understand why.

I ROFLED about the guideline where the messages shouldn't be condescending or corporate-sounding.  :D

Answer (score 5):

Read [The Elements of Style](http://www.bartleby.com/141/).  Then re-read it.

Also, anytime you are working with a program or website make a conscious effort to notice how they choose to do their writing. Imitate those you like.

Comment: Strunk & White is amazing. The Little Book changed the way I write *and* read.

Comment: Strunk&White is good for getting across the idea of good style and why it matters, but it (and Orwell's much-recommended *Politics and the English Language*) are lousy as real style guides: their prescriptions are not very useful.  Read them, put them away on your bookshelf, and then get to grips with a real style/usage guide, like the APA Publication Manual or Fowler's Modern English Usage.

Answer (score 4):

The resources found at [Writing for the Web](http://www.useit.com/papers/webwriting/) might be useful to you.

Comment: I am fan of Nielsen, and the link above is a great when creating web sites.

Answer (score 3):

The best tool for this is called "primary education".  Many developers seem to have missed this, and I don't know how to fix that problem.

Also, this may be a British thing, but I think you mean "humor" and "going to Hell in a handbasket".  :)

Comment: Like pubs and standing up to Hitler? :)

Comment: Like warm beer, rounders, and not asking "Hi, how are you today?" unless you *actually* want to know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This book has a lot of good advice:

[GUI Bloopers 2.0](http://www.gui-bloopers.com/)

Short version:

1. Be consistent throughout your application or app suite. Don't call the same feature two different names, even if they're in different dialogs, etc. Develop a product lexicon that everyone references.
2. Use the same terms that people who use your software use (i.e. users don't refer to themselves as users).
3. Don't call two different things by the same name.
4. Put all of the messages displayed to the user in a central place (i.e. a resources file of some kind). This makes it easy to review all of the messages for spelling, tone, consistency, and whatever else you want to check.
5. Usability test your software to see if the messages make sense and people can use your software easily. If they can't, change the resources file and test it again.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest showing your UI to as many people as you can--preferably people who read a lot (Just because reading does wonders for your grammar and vocabulary).

Getting something out that people can examine, however, is awesome--even if it's just a demo of the GUI.

If you work at a company, get to know your QA and Tech Support people.  They are usually really wonderful once they understand what you are trying to do--they will review your UI, give you input on text and usability as well as possibly new requirements nobody in engineering would come up with.

If you work on your own, try to find a potential customer or two to review your UI.  Ask them to pay attention to the text...

The more eyes, the better.  You might even ask your parents, wife or other family.  What can it hurt?

Answer (score 1):

Get your application's texts proofread by someone who does just that for a living.  Then the UI walked through by someone who does usability for a living.  Neither of these two people should have been involved in the development.

It's the only way to make sure.